# phonegap installation error on windows 7 64 bit

Tags: cordova, installation, npm, phonegap-build

I got problem when I install phonegap by

```
npm install phonegap -g
```

I got tons of errors headed by

```
bufferutil.cc
C:\Users\loppp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(213): error C2039: “ThrowException”: no member named 'ThrowException' in 'v8::String';
[C:\Users\loppp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]

C:\Users\loppp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\nan\nan.h(213): error C2039: no member named 'New' in 'v8::String';     
[C:\Users\loppp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\connect-phonegap\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\build\bufferutil.vcxproj]

C:\Users\loppp\.node-gyp\0.12.3\deps\v8\include\v8.h(1599) :see declaration of 'v8::String'
```

I've trapped here for couple of hours, anyone can help me out?

ps, the version information printed out right after npm install phonegap -g:

```
npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.9.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.3","npm":"2.9.1"})
npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"0.12.3","npm":"2.9.1"})
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.3","npm":"2.9.1"})
```

Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
"colors": "0.6.0-1",
"connect-phonegap": "0.16.0",
"cordova": "5.0.0",
"minimist": "0.1.0",
"phonegap-build": "0.9.1",
"pluralize": "0.0.4",
"prompt": "0.2.11",
"qrcode-terminal": "0.9.4",
"semver": "1.1.0",
"shelljs": "0.1.4"
},
```

Comment: check your version of npm and maybe try to empty the folder C:\Users\loppp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\phonegap ? Or try to install cordova instead

Comment: npm is the latest. I tried npm uninstall phonegap -g, moreover, I unistalled all npm modules, and install phonegap again, nothing changes.

Comment: have you tried `npm install -g cordova` ? (do you really need phonegap and not cordova?)

Comment: Hi QuickFix, thank you for answering my question. I am a newbie to phonegap, I just need a easy tool doing cross development. It looks to me that phonegap is easier than cordova as the cordova is wrapped by the phonegap ?

Comment: phonegap adds some stuffs to cordova and has an online build tool. phonegap adds complexity (for some commands you run phonegap cli, for others you run cordova), it often is a few version late compared to cordova... If you're begining and don't need something that's specific to phonegap, I'd recommend you just use cordova for the moment.

Comment: ok, thanks so much for your explanation, I started over with cordova and now everything looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed it today. Just delete other paths and keep your system and user $PATH simple:

C:\python27_x64;C:\Users\ **USERNAME** \AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;C:\Users\ **USERNAME** \AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin